# How to change bands color in ggAcf function from R

Tags: r, ggplot2, autocorrelation

I am trying to plot Autcorrelation Function from a time series. I'm using `ggplot`function `ggAcf` and I've got the next graph

[image]

This is my code

```
    acf_or<-ggAcf(data_or$y, lag.max=100)+
    theme(axis.text = element_text(size=base*expand), axis.title = element_text(size=base*expand))+
    ggtitle("")+labs(x="", y="")+ylim(c(-1,1))
```

I would like to make some changes to confidence interval lines, like color, width and linetype. Is there any option to do it changing some parameters in the function `ggAcf`?

Comment: Can you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of the dataset you are plotting with `ggAcf` ?

Comment: You can generate a time series using, for example, `rnorm(10000)`.

Answer (score 1):

The code for ggAcf is [here on Github](https://github.com/robjhyndman/forecast/blob/master/R/ggplot.R) as part of the `forecast` package. It's pretty readable, and you'll see that extra parameters to ggAcf are eventually passed into `geom_segment` -- so you might alter some of those aesthetics of the line segments, but not the confidence intervals.

For customizing the plot and confidence intervals specifically, you might try using the ggAcf code as a model, or other SO entries like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788859/acf-plot-with-ggplot2-setting-width-of-geom-bar) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42753017/adding-confidence-intervals-to-plotted-acf-in-ggplot2) to build up your own plot.